# Git/IntelliJ - applying some default changes whenever I branch from master

Tags: git, configuration, repository, config, branching-and-merging

I'm working a project (Java/Gradle/Spring) in short.
Whenever I get a ticket from Jira and create a new branch from master, I have to apply some set of changes to a few config files (sometimes even run configs), like JVM version, some location of other config files to run it locally.

Yet, I have to remove them before reshipping it to master. The problem is not removing my changes, this is trivial, I store them in a separate commit that I'll later discard. I'd really like to apply them whenever I fork from master (or even from other branches).

Is there any way to set up something to apply these changes automatically (preferably via Bash, Git or IntelliJ)? (not sure if cherry-picking from a local branch, using stashes/shelves).
What do you suggest me to try, simple and straight forward?

Comment: Make yourself an alias or function (or Git alias): "create branch and cherry-pick standard stuff in as a first new commit" or something along those lines.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the suggestion. Will probably go with your suggestion. But, I still would like to hear other opiniond, perhaps there's some `git` feature that I don't know about neither couldn't find that does it or something similar. :) @torek, thanks.